# Xcode 8 crashes all the time

Tags: xcode8

I open my project(mac app) in xcode, i launch the simulator, everything works fine. If i enter some specific characters in a textfield, xcode crashes with the following report but the simulator keeps working.

I have uninstalled and installed xcode. i deleted the developer folder, nothing of these resolved the problem.

Any ideas why is this happening?

```
 Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: appendConsoleItemLock

 Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
 Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
 Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

 Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
 Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
 Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

Comment: Try creating a new user on your machine.  Log in as that user and try running Xcode.  If it's OK, then there's probably something corrupt in `~/Library/...` of the old account.  If it fails, I have no idea.

Comment: Hi Phillip, i did as instructed but unfortunately the error remains! Any idea what that crashed thread mean?

Comment: did you figure this out? I have something similar, but another app than xcode.

Comment: Nope! I am pulling my hair out.. have you found any solution? Do you have the crash when you enter emojis?

Comment: I'm having the same issue for now. when I am coding, suddenly xcode crashes.

Comment: what I did and worked for me was to disable the source control option that is integrated in Xcode:  `Xcode > Preferences > Source Control > Enable Source Control`